# Handoff to an agent using Microsoft Bot Composer

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, bot-framework-composer

I have a requirement to transfer conversation from a bot to an agent using Microsoft bot framework. For this purpose I am using the following resource.

https://github.com/cdonke/Botframework-Composer-Handover

I am able to successfully setup the application but User is unable to send message to the agent even after agent has successfully accepted the request from the user. I have also tried to debug the code by attaching it to the process still it is not showing any error but does not route the message from one channel to another channel.

- Agent Successfully accepted the request.

[image]

- User sending **Hello** to the agent but unable to send the message.

[image]

Can anyone help me in this regards if I am missing anything?

Comment: It looks like you're saying you tried using someone else's code from their personal repo and it's not working. Have you considered reaching out to the person who made that repo by raising an issue in the repo?

Comment: Are you still working on this?